# combine duplicate pairs of polygons

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, spatial

I ran into a problem with my code. This code finds unique pairs of polygons that are less than 100 m apart. How can duplicate pairs be merged?

[image: output data]

Here's my code:

```sql
select s1.id, s2.id, 
    ST_distance(
      ST_Transform(s1.geom,3857),
      ST_Transform(s2.geom,3857)),
   s1.geom 
from shops as s1, shops as s2
where ST_distance(
       ST_Transform(s1.geom,3857),
       ST_Transform(s2.geom,3857))<100 
 and s1.id<>s2.id
```

Comment: You should include the code directly in the question, don't link to an image of it.

Comment: Also, I don't think ST_Distance() will return units of metres if you're using projection 3857. You should use projection 4326 for that.

Comment: Please post the queries and data as text, not images.

Comment: On a side note, never ever compute distances in 3857 as this projection highly distorts them. Use a suitable local projection that preserves distances or use geography or use ST_DistanceSphere. In the where clause, have a look at st_dwithin instead, as it makes use of spatial index

Comment: @SteveBennett unit of 3857 is meters, so the result will be in meters... though it is a meaningless distance because of the distortion. st_distance on 4326 will return a distance in degrees, which is even more meaningless.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, thanks @JGH.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` condition you're using will select each pair of `shops.id`s twice (once with the higher ID in `s1` and the other time with the higher ID in `s2`).  So instead, add a stricter condition:

```
WHERE ...
AND s1.id < s2.id
```